# scroll bar in popup panel in GWT

Tags: gwt, popup

I have a popup panel which opens on a button click event. Popup panel height should be fixed and if contents of popup panel exceeds the height of popup panel, then a vertical scroll bar needs to be attached to it, and i should be able to scroll it to see the contents.  I am displaying a flex table in the pop up and the flex table rows and columns vary for different kinds of inputs. so, if the flex table size is bigger than pop up, scroll bar should appear to pop up. I tried with overflow:scroll in my css, but it didn't work. is it because of the flex table? How to achieve this when i have different widgets place in my pop up? Can any body please help?

Thanks,
Sreenivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a ScrollPanel into your PopupPanel and then a FlexTable into your ScrollPanel.

You can find doc - http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html

Example - http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Panels~ScrollPanel

Comment: yes. I did that. But then my content when exceeding the popup panel is coming out of the pop up panel.

Comment: You have probably run into this issue - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=889  You can solve it by setting size height/width appropriately.

Comment: The gwt bug describes setting up height for scroll panel with gwt code and not from css.

Comment: i set the height of popup panel in css. my code order is like this: 1.create a popup panel 2.create a scroll panel 3.create a vertical panel 4.create a flex table and button 5. add flex table, button to vertical panel 6.add vertical panel to scroll bar 7.add scroll bar to popup panel 8.add popup panel to my button click event. Can you plese figure out am i doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you set the height of the ScrollPanel in gwt code. Avoid setting height for flextable or popup in css.